# How do I add two functions together and store in another function(a third function) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, addition

Pls how do I add this two functions I declared and store into another function(a third function) so I will be able to call the addition of the result of both functions using the third function?

```js
function myFunc() {

  var grade1 = document.getElementById("grade").value;

  var unit = 3;

  var tUnits = 18;

  switch (grade1) {
    case 'a':
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (5 * unit / tUnits);
      break;
    case 'b':
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (4 * unit / tUnits);
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Please input a valid grade';
  }
  return grade1;
}


function myFunc2() {

  var grade2 = document.getElementById("grade2").value;

  var unit2 = 3

  var tUnits = 18

  switch (grade2) {
    case 'a':
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = (10 * unit2 / tUnits);
      break;
    case 'b':

    default:
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Please input a valid grade';
  }
}
```

That is the code above!

Comment: The two functions are practically identical. The only difference is `grade` versus `grade2`. Why don't you just make it one function that takes the element ID as a parameter?

Comment: The other difference is the value of each grade. You can put that information in nested objects that use the ID and grade as keys.

Comment: Are you looking for `Func() + Func2()`?

Comment: Note that your functions don't return numbers, they return the letter grades. So when you add them together, it will concatenate the grades, not add the numbers that you're putting in the `demo` element.

Comment: Your functions both update the same `demo` element. So if you run both of them, it will just contain the value for one of the grades. It sounds like you should change the functions to return the numeric grade, then the caller can display the combined results.

Comment: This is not the complete code, I'm actually looking for a way to get Func() + Func2(), like you said  so as to store it in another function to call using onclick... Can you help me?

Comment: Put `let variable = Func() + Func2()` in another function.

Comment: I think you're confused about what "return" means. They display a number in the `demo` DIV, but they end with `return grade1;`, which returns the grade letter that was in the input field.

Comment: I appreciate for your responses Barmar,      I used the let variable like you said and only myFunc2() was run. in this manner;       function myFunc3() { let variable = myFunc() + myFunc(); }    am I right? Unfortunately only myFunc2() was printed instead of the sum of both functions.. Pls is there another way I can do this?

Comment: How could you tell that only MyFunc2 was run? As I pointed out above, they both display their results in the same DIV. So after you run both functions, you only see the second result.

Comment: Because it overwrites the result from the first function.

Comment: Use `console.log(variable)` in the third function, and you'll see the concatenated grades.

Comment: Exactly, Func2 overwrites the first function like you said... Is there a way to stop the overwriting and add them both stored into another function?

Comment: Like I said above, you should change your functions so they return the value instead of putting it in the innerHTML. Then the caller can combine the results.

Comment: OK, pls can you emphasize more about how I will do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your functions so they return the result instead of putting it in `innerHTML`. Then you can have another function that calls both of them and displays both results.

```js
function myFunc() {
  var grade1 = document.getElementById("grade").value;
  var unit = 3;
  var tUnits = 18;

  switch (grade1) {
    case 'a':
      return (5 * unit / tUnits);
      break;
      
    case 'b':
      return (4 * unit / tUnits);
      break;
      
    default:
      return 'Please input a valid grade';
  }
}


function myFunc2() {
  var grade2 = document.getElementById("grade2").value;
  var unit2 = 3
  var tUnits = 18

  switch (grade2) {
    case 'a':
      return (10 * unit2 / tUnits);
      break;
      
    case 'b':
    default:
      return 'Please input a valid grade';
  }
}

function combinedFunc() {
  let class1 = myFunc();
  let class2 = myFunc2();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = `Class 1: ${class1}, Class 2: ${class2}`;
}
```

```html
<select id="grade">
<option value="">Grade for Class 1</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
</select>

<select id="grade2">
<option value="">Grade for Class 2</option>
<option value="a">A</option>
<option value="b">B</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="combinedFunc()">Show Grades</button>
<p>
Grades:
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function myFunc() {
  var grade1 = document.getElementById("grade").value;
  var unit = 3;
  var tUnits = 18;
  // declare variable output
  var output;
  
  switch (grade1) {
      case 'a':
          output = (5 * unit / tUnits);
      break;
      case 'b':
           output = (4 * unit / tUnits);
      break;
      default:
          output = 'Please input a valid grade';
    }
    // return output
    return output;
  }

  function myFunc2() {
     var grade2 = document.getElementById("grade2").value;
     var unit2 = 3;
     var tUnits = 18;
     // declare output
     var output;

     switch (grade2) {
         case 'a':
              output = (10 * unit2 / tUnits);
          break;
        case 'b':

        default:
              output = 'Please input a valid grade';
       }
       // return output
       return output;
     }

    function myFunc3() {
     // get the value returned by myFunc
     var funcA = myFunc();
     // get value returned by myFunc2
     var funcB = myFunc2();

     // if the  value  returned by both function is a number , add up the result 
    if (typeof funcA === 'number' && typeof funcB === 'number'){
     
        ​document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML =  funcA + funcB;
      
     } else {
       // output error message to the user
      ​document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'please input a valid grade';

    }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked bro... Where do you reside in Lag?

Comment: You're welcome bro. I reside in Anambra State at the moment.